# Use R-function "nls" to estimate GEV parameters

Tags: r, nls

I want to estimate the parameters of a GEV (generalized extreme value) distribution using the method of weighted least squares. I use R, and I found a function called nls which I think might be used for this purpose. It asks for a formula and an optional dataset. I guess the GEV formula and annual maxima series should in here, but I am not sure how. Has anyone used nls and has any idea on how to do this?

```
#Vector of ranged annual maxima
x <- c(21,24,29,32,32,34,35,35,35,36,37,37,38,40,40,41,43,47,47,52)
w <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
data <- list(x=x,w=w)
nls(y ~ exp(-(1+((x-location)/scale))^(-1/shape)),data=data, weights=w,start=list(location=5,scale=2,shape=0.10))
```

The error says that y is missing. y is what we get when we optimize the GEV parameters, so that y becomes as close to x as possible for all x's (also depending on the weights). So y is unknown until we have estimated the GEV parameters...

Comment: Yes, `nls` is heavily used by a lot of people. Give us [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) and we can help you.

Comment: I added an example, although it is not very useful since my problem is that I don't know how to formulate the code.

Comment: What is `x`? The `data` parameter expects a data.frame containing `am`, `x`, and `w`. You need to give starting values to `nls`, e.g., `start=list(location=...,scale=...,shape=...`. It's your job to find these starting values.

Comment: x is actually am when I think about it. I updated the question and code.

Comment: You need both x and y values for regression.

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland commented, you need to have two variables to do a regression. In this case, you only have one: the observed values for the GEV. As such you don't actually want to fit the distribution using `nls`, but some other algorithm, for example maximum likelihood. See the package `evd` which has functions to deal with GEVs including fitting them from data.

Comment: thank you. I have fitted GEV to the data using both maximum likelihood and probability weighted moments. The reason why I wanted to use nls is that I wanted to try a method called "weighted least squares", which I can't find enough information about to program from scratch.